# Error copying files from successful build using command line or artifact

Tags: teamcity, teamcity-9.0

I have built a new server with TeamCity v9.0. I am having difficulty trying to copy the build output to a mapped network drive `X:`.

My build steps are as follows:

1. Get latest version from TFS online.
2. Build using MSBuild
3. Run NUnit tests
4. Copy two folders (Web and ServiceLayer) to a mapped network drive `X:`

### Attempted but can not get working:

1. **Created a final build step with the following `Command Line` script:**

> xcopy %system.teamcity.build.workingDir%\ServiceLayer\
>   D:\ServiceLayer\ /S /Y
>
> xcopy %system.teamcity.build.workingDir%\Web\
>   D:\Web\ /S /Y

*Error*:

> Step 4/5: Copy build output to web and api on staging (Command Line)
>
> teamcity[buildStatisticValue key='buildStageDuration:firstStepPreparation' value='70.0']
>
> teamcity[buildStatisticValue key='buildStageDuration:buildStepRUNNER_8' value='0.0'] Starting:
>
> D:\TeamCity\buildAgent\temp\agentTmp\custom_script9113406165823545108.cmd
>
> in directory: D:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\3b1161c630069aad 0 File(s)
>
> copied Invalid path Process exited with code 4
>
> teamcity[buildStatisticValue key='buildStageDuration:buildStepRUNNER_8' value='194.0'] Step Copy
>
> build output to web and api on staging (Command Line) failed

2. **Created an artifact path**

> ServiceLayer => d:\Temp\x.zip
>   
>   *Error:*
>
> Failed to publish artifacts: Failed to upload artifact, due to error:
>
> java.io.IOException: Failed to create directory:
>
> "C:\ProgramData\JetBrains\TeamCity\system\artifacts\ChannelOptimiser40\CO40
>   Build Config\224\d:\Temp"

**Question**

Can someone please tell me how I can copy my `ServiceLayer` and `Web` folders to another directory when the build completes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the source and destination paths and it copied the directories.

From

> xcopy %system.teamcity.build.workingDir%\ServiceLayer\
>   D:\ServiceLayer\ /S /Y

To

> xcopy ServiceLayer \\SomeNetworkPC\Site\ServiceLayer\ /S /Y